# Changing Tabs with AspxPageControl

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I have a problem about changing tabs in my AspxPageControl.I use this tool for showing my web pages dynamically. When I change my active tab, the old tab vanishes. I searched a bit and found this problem can be fixed with saving states in cache or session.

However I am really rookie about developing web apps. How can I do that ? I also used jquery ui on my project but it didn't work. So I changed my project with this tool. Also I could take advice about tabpages that have dynamic webpages in.

This button basicly adds a new page on my tab and set active page this tab:

```
protected void bt_yeniEklenenler_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        YeniEklenen_count= YeniEklenen_count + 1;

        TabPage tab = new TabPage();
        tab.Text = "Yeni Eklenenler";
        tab.Name = "tab_yenieklenenler" + YeniEklenen_count.ToString();


        LiteralControl l = new LiteralControl("<iframe src='YeniEklenenler.aspx' runat='client' id='frm2' style='width: 99 %; height: 78vh; margin - top:20px'></ iframe >");


        l.ID = "lit_yenieklenenler" + YeniEklenen_count.ToString();

        tab.Controls.Add(l);

        ASPxPageControl1.TabPages.Add(tab);

        ASPxPageControl1.ActiveTabPage = ASPxPageControl1.TabPages.FindByName(tab.Name);



    }
```

And my design source:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:Button ID="bt_yeniEklenenler" runat="server" OnClick="bt_yeniEklenenler_Click" Text="Yeni Eklenenler" OnClientClick="ButtonClick();" />
        <asp:Button ID="bt_kampanya" runat="server" Text="Kampanya" OnClick="bt_kampanya_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="bt_fiyatListesi" runat="server" Text="Fiyat Listesi" OnClick="bt_fiyatListesi_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="bt_sepetim" runat="server" Text="Sepetim" OnClick="bt_sepetim_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="bt_siparisListesi" runat="server" Text="Sipariş Listesi" OnClick="bt_siparisListesi_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="bt_firmaBilgileri" runat="server" Text="Firma Bilgileri" OnClick="bt_firmaBilgileri_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="bt_cariHareket" runat="server" Text="Cari Hareket" OnClick="bt_cariHareket_Click" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="KAPAT" />
        <dx:ASPxPageControl runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" RenderMode="Lightweight" Width="1146px" Height="555px" ID="ASPxPageControl1" OnActiveTabChanged="ASPxPageControl1_ActiveTabChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
            <TabPages>
                <dx:TabPage Text="Ana Sayfa">
                    <ContentCollection>
                        <dx:ContentControl runat="server" SupportsDisabledAttribute="True">
                            <h1 style="text-align:center">_____ SİSTEMİNE HOŞGELDİNİZ...</h1>
                            <h1 style="text-align:center">&nbsp;</h1>
                            <h1 style="text-align:center">
                                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="KAPAT" />
                            </h1>
                        </dx:ContentControl>
                    </ContentCollection>
                </dx:TabPage>
            </TabPages>

        </dx:ASPxPageControl>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Note: I tried turn on AutoPostBack also, but then my tab don't change when I click another tab.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: does it preserve the newly created tabpage after postback.. try using clientside events to modify/add tab pages. After that try to set selected tab page using page controls client side methods.

Comment: no it doesn't preserve new tab.

Comment: that what i am saying..it will not preserve. either you do it on client side and block postback to reset the html

Comment: I tried client side solution but this component stricted about that. I will try second advise. I blocked postback. How can I reset the html ?

Comment: Check [this - google results](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=aspxpagecontrol%20client%20side%20events). It will help you to implement lots of the task client side. There are lots of DevEx questions and knowledge base link for client side implementations.. Hope these help

Answer (score 0):

**Refer these:**
[ASPxPageControl - how to add a new page using Client-Side Scripts](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q362613)
[ASPxPageControl - How to add tab on client side](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q566532)
[AspxPageControl add tabpage dynamically](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q219611)

You can try adding a tab page using the javascript(client side methods) and after that you can set the active tab. Try using the the client side [ASPxClientTabControlBase.SetActiveTab](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxTabControlScriptsASPxClientTabControlBase_SetActiveTabtopic) method

[ASPxPageControl how to ActiveTabChanged event after client side event to get data first](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q238716)
[ASPxPageControl clientside event ActiveTabChanged](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q303322)
[ASPxPageControl - How to set an active tab on the client-side](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q401828)

Hope these help you to implement the functionality as you want to do.